# MTIColorLookupFilter of MetalPetal output incorrect result

Tags: ios, image-processing, metal, lookup-tables

I test the MTIColorLookupFilter of [MetalPetal framework](https://github.com/MetalPetal/MetalPetal) with the default lookup image [lookup.png](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Resources/lookup.png) on Iphone 6 iOS 9.3.1 but the result image was strange as below image. When I tried to test on Iphone 6 iOS 12.0 the result was correct as I expected. Please help me to fix it!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem. See https://github.com/MetalPetal/MetalPetal/issues/67